# Why isn't my datagridview being populated after setting the datasource?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, datasource, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a vb.net Windows forms application.  I've got a datagridview that I'm trying to populate by a datatable and cannot get it to show the data.  I've tried assigning the datatable directly to datagridview and using a binding source.  I've checked the column names and tried to refresh the grid after setting the datasource.  If I go back into the code, I can see that the datasource has data, but data will not appear in the grid.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the database table creation:

```
Dim dsReturns As New DataSet("Returns Dataset")
Dim dtReturns = dsReturns.Tables.Add("Returns Datatable")
dtReturns.Columns.Add("Quantity")
dtReturns.Columns.Add("ItemName")
Dim drReturns As DataRow = dtReturns.NewRow
drReturns("Quantity") = qtyh(key).ToString
drReturns("ItemName") = ItemFunctions.GetItemName(item_id)
dsReturns.Tables("Returns Datatable").Rows.Add(drReturns)
```

This produces a datatable that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code assigning the datatable to the datagridview.  I've tried it both with and without using the binding source.

```
dgvReturns = new DataGridView()
Dim bsReturns As New BindingSource()
bsReturns.DataSource = dsReturns.Tables("Returns Datatable")
dgvReturns.DataSource = bsReturns
```

Here's the code from the Designer that creates the datagridview.  I didn't write the code, it's all auto generated. I created a new datagridview in Design mode and then added two columns.

```
Friend WithEvents dgvReturns As DataGridView
Friend WithEvents Quantity As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ItemName As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Me.dgvReturns = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
Me.Quantity = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
Me.ItemName = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
CType(Me.dgvReturns,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit
Me.dgvReturns.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
Me.dgvReturns.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.Quantity, Me.ItemName})
Me.Quantity.DataPropertyName = "Quantity"
Me.Quantity.HeaderText = "Quantity Returned"
Me.Quantity.Name = "Quantity"
Me.ItemName.HeaderText = "Item Name"
Me.ItemName.Name = "ItemName"
Me.dgvReturns.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
Me.dgvReturns.Name = "dgvReturns"
Me.dgvReturns.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(465, 150)
Me.dgvReturns.TabIndex = 1
Me.Controls.Add(Me.dgvReturns)
CType(Me.dgvReturns,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit
```

Here's a screenshot of the table in the Designer:

[image]

All I end up with is a blank grid:

[image]

Update #1 - Showing all code for the form

Here's the full code for the form showing the constructor.

```
Public Class frmReturnsDialog
    Public Sub New(dsReturns As DataSet)
        InitializeComponent()
        dgvReturns = new DataGridView()
        Dim bsReturns As New BindingSource()
        bsReturns.DataSource = dsReturns.Tables("Returns Datatable")
        dgvReturns.DataSource = bsReturns
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `dgvReturns = new DataGridView()`  This looks like a new grid that isn't part of the control collection.  You shouldn't need it if the control already exists on the form.

Comment: Without that line I get an "object does not exist" error on the line dgvReturns.DataSource = bsReturns.  DataSource shows as null when I do a quick watch on it.  Found an answer on SO saying a new DataGridView hadn't been created.  If I don't need the "new" declaration, any idea how to get around the error?

Comment: Where did you insert the code that fills the DataSet/DataTable and assigns the DataSource? Some place where the original DGV has already been created or not? Same Form? As LarsTech said, this: `dgvReturns = new DataGridView()` it's a new, different DGV. Not the one you defined in the Designer.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting "object does not exist" error when you remove that `dgvReturns = new DataGridView()` line, since that grid should already exist on the form since the designer can modify it.